# Obtaining the complex roots of a 2nd degree polynomial in pascal

Tags: pascal, complex-numbers

I have to code a program in pascal that, given the three coefficients of a polynomial(ax²+bx+c), outputs its roots.

Here's what I have right now:

```
program poly;

type
    polynomial = record
                 a, b, c : real;
                end;

procedure readPolynomial (var p : polynomial);
      begin
        writeln ('Input 1st coefficient: ');
        readln (p.a);

        writeln ('Input 2nd coefficient: ');
        readln (p.b);

        writeln ('Input 3rd coefficient: ');
        readln (p.c);
      end;


function square (x : real) : real;
     begin
        square := x * x; 
     end;

procedure roots (p : polynomial; var rP, rN : real);
      begin
        rP := (-p.b + (sqrt((square(p.b)) - (4 * p.a * p.c)))) / (2 * p.a); 
        rN := (-p.b - (sqrt((square(p.b)) - (4 * p.a * p.c)))) / (2 * p.a);

        writeln('The roots are: ', rP:0:3, ' y ' ,rN:0:3);
      end;

var
myPolynomial : polynomial;
r1, r2      : real;

begin
    writeln ('Enter the coefficients: ');
    readPolynomial (myPolynomial);

    roots (myPolynomial, r1, r2);

end.
```

It works fine for real roots but I don't know how to make it work with complex numbers.

Comment: Do you mean complex coefficients a,b,c? Or do you only want to handle the case with real coefficients and a negative discriminant? In this case look here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_equation#Discriminant

Comment: People will often ask clarifying questions shortly after a question is posted, so it's a good idea to stay on the site for a while and look for those questions. Otherwise your question may be downvoted and/or closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming your coefficients are *real* numbers (they user can't enter complex numbers as coefficients). That would add a whole new level of complexity (no pun intended) to the problem.

You need to check the *discriminant* (`(square(p.b)) - (4 * p.a * p.c)`) to see if it's less than 0. Currently, your code just does, `sqrt((square(p.b)) - (4 * p.a * p.c))` but you aren't checking if you are taking the square root of a negative number (which you can't do using the Pascal `sqrt` library function).

If the discriminant is negative, then you have a complex root and you can separate the real and imaginary parts as you wish in your program. It's basic [quadratic formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_formula).

For example:

```
procedure roots (p : polynomial; var rP, rN : real);
var disc: real;
  begin
    disc := square(p.b) - 4*p.a*p.c;

    if disc >= 0 then begin
      rP := (-p.b + sqrt(disc)) / (2 * p.a); 
      rN := (-p.b - sqrt(disc)) / (2 * p.a);

      writeln('The roots are: ', rP:0:3, ' y ' ,rN:0:3);
    end
    else begin
       // Roots are:
       //   -p.b/(2*p.a) + (sqrt(-disc)/(2*p.a))i
       //   -p.b/(2*p.a) - (sqrt(-disc)/(2*p.a))i
    end
  end;
```

Here you use the fact that `sqrt(x)` if `x` is negative would be, `(sqrt(-x))i` where `i` is `sqrt(-1)`. Note that you could also split out the `disc = 0` case to avoid repeating a *double root*.

Since your `roots` function prints out the results and your main program doesn't use the returned arguments `rN` and `rP`, it's not clear to me if you need to pass back the roots at all. But if want to pass the roots back as arguments (the way you have your function currently designed), I'll leave that as an exercise. You just have to decide on a representation for complex roots. One way is to use the `Complex` number type for the results (if your compiler library supports them), and when the results are real, the imaginary parts will just be zero. Alternatively, if you need to create your own, just make a `type` which is a `record` consisting of a *real* and *imaginary* part.

```
type complex = record
  re: real;
  im: real;
end;
```